# 6.2.2 liferay-ui:input-date in Liferay.AutoFields stopped to works

Tags: liferay

Migrating from 6.1 to 6.22, liferay-ui:input-date in Liferay.AutoFields stopped to works.

I have a form managed by Liferay.AutoFields and all fields are read but the liferay-ui:input-date fails
In liferay-portlet.xml I put false

In 6.1 the below code works, but in 6.2.2 the only fields missing is the date one:

```
aui:form name="<portlet:namespace/>fm" action="<%= editStagioneURL.toString() %>" method="post">

     <aui:fieldset cssClass="<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()+\"stagiones\"%>">

         <%
         for (int l = 0; l < stagiones.size(); l++) {

             OMStagione curStagione = stagiones.get(l);
         %>

        <div class="lfr-form-row lfr-form-row-inline">

            <div class="row-fields">

                <aui:layout>

                    <aui:column columnWidth="25" first="true">

                        <%
                            Calendar sDate = CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar(timeZone, locale);
                                if (Validator.isNotNull(curStagione.getStartDate())) {
                                    sDate.setTime(curStagione.getStartDate());
                                } else {
                                    sDate.setTime(new Date());
                                }
                        %>
                        <liferay-ui:input-date
                            dayParam="<%= \"startDay\" + l %>"
                            dayValue="<%= sDate.get(Calendar.DATE) %>"
                            firstDayOfWeek="<%= sDate.getFirstDayOfWeek() %>"
                            monthParam="<%= \"startMonth\" + l %>"
                            monthValue="<%= sDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) %>"
                            yearParam="<%= \"startYear\" + l %>"
                            yearValue="<%= sDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) %>" >
                        </liferay-ui:input-date>

                    </aui:column>

                </aui:layout>

            </div>

        </div>

        <%
         }
         %>

         <aui:button-row>

             <aui:button
                 type="submit"
                 disabled="<%=saveButtonDisabled %>"
                  first="true"
              />

         </aui:button-row>

    </aui:fieldset>

</aui:form>

<aui:script use="liferay-auto-fields">
    new Liferay.AutoFields(
        {
            contentBox: 'fieldset.<portlet:namespace />stagiones',
            fieldIndexes: '<portlet:namespace />stagioniIndexes'
        }
    ).render();
</aui:script>
```

Comment: Hi Olaf ! Thank you to reply me.  The "+ l" added to startDay, startMonth and startYear add a progressive number about how much rows are created by the user using Liferay.AutoFields +/- button. Then in my processAction() I get startDay0, startsDay1 and so on - then I compose the Date variable.
In 6.1.1 all is good but in 6.2.2 I can't get startDayx, startMonthx, starYearx cause are null - all other kind of input fields are ok.

Thank you in advance for more helps - the issue blocked me since many days.

Comment: Hi Olaf, after one more day of trying I'll confirm you that there is this issue: 
In 6.2.2 liferay-ui:input-date in Liferay.AutoFields stopped don't works.
Only the first row of Liferay.Autofields is returned in parameters. In subseguent row alla date firlds are null. 
I'll open a Liferay's issue on this.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Just from looking at it, I'm not sure what the string operations in your tag usage do, e.g. `dayParam="<%= \"startDay\" + l %>"`: For startDay of 1, I'd expect this to result in `dayParam="<%= \"1\" + l %>"`, or is my head playing games with me?</del> (Sorry, I'm not using this tag too often - of course, you're constructing the HTTP parameter names, and this notation totally messed up my personal parsing. Thanks for the clarification in the comments)

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/taglib/ui/input_date/page.jsp#L88) of the tag, I see that the implementation has a different behavior in included AUI modules depending on the browser - e.g. [mobile or not](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/servlet/BrowserSnifferImpl.java#L234).

I know, no definitive answer, but maybe this helps already? Can you check browsers that trigger different modules - e.g. the mobile and the non-mobile?

Comment: Hi Olaf ! Thank you to reply me.  The "+ l" added to startDay, startMonth and startYear add a progressive number about how much rows are created by the user using Liferay.AutoFields +/- button. Then in my processAction() I get startDay0, startsDay1 and so on - then I compose the Date variable.
In 6.1.1 all is good but in 6.2.2 I can't get startDayx, startMonthx, starYearx cause are null - all other kind of input fields are ok.

Thank you in advance for more helps - the issue blocked me since many days.

Comment: In processAction I do the following:

for (int stagioniIndex : stagioniIndexes) {

int startDateMonth = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, startDateMonth" + stagioniIndex);
int startDateDay = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "startDateDay" + stagioniIndex);
int startDateYear = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "startDateYear" + stagioniIndex);
Date startDate = PortalUtil.getDate(startDateMonth, startDateDay, startDateYear);
<omissis>

Comment: I'm trying the portlet using commons web browsers as IE, FF, Chrome. 

In the 6.1.x I don't need to take care of the browser.

I don't understand why I have to take care of the browser to use a liferay-ui tag or the Liferay.AutoFields.

I'm very confused ...

Comment: it's just a guess - if you follow the links that I've posted, you'll see that there's some conditional AUI module inclusion, depending on the result of BrowserSnifferUtil.isMobile(request). If there's an issue with one of the modules, but not the other, that might give you a hint where to look for the root cause / fix.

Comment: I see ... but if this is rhe result, then liferay-ui:input-date in the 6.2.2 is wrong using all kind of web browser. Unfortunately I'm not able to test mobile browsers.
 Do you suggest me to open an issue on Liferay issues ?

Comment: I'm seeing that it is an issue of liferay-ui-input-date also outside Liferay.AutoFields .....

Comment: Hi Olaf, after one more day of trying I'll confirm you that there is this issue: 
In 6.2.2 liferay-ui:input-date in Liferay.AutoFields stopped don't works.
Only the first row of Liferay.Autofields is returned in parameters. In subseguent row alla date firlds are null. 
I'll open a Liferay's issue on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you print all parameters , do you see your parameters printed. I am trying to find if you are getting your values in request or not.

Comment: This is the problem: I don't get value in the parameters passed to the processAction:

---> DEBUG: stagioniIndexes = 1

---> DEBUG: startDateMonth1 = 0
---> DEBUG: startDateDay1 = 0
---> DEBUG: startDateYear1 = 0

Comment: After one more day of trying I'll confirm you that there is this issue: 
In 6.2.2 liferay-ui:input-date in Liferay.AutoFields stopped don't works.
Only the first row of Liferay.Autofields is returned in parameters. In subseguent row alla date firlds are null. 
I'll open a Liferay's issue on this.